# How to position two divs on the absolute front of a page, but with one over the other? CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a custom overlay popup. To do it, I'm laying a masking `div` over the page with `width/height` at `100%` and `opacity` at `0.8`. The popup is another `div` laid on top of the masking `div`.

I'm writing a function to hide these two `div`s if the masking `div` is clicked on. This will 'close' the popup window.

To test this function I'm using a Javascript alert. I've noticed the alert is still triggered when clicking on the popup `div`, not just the masking `div`. This indicates that the popup `div` is not positioned to the absolute front. I've also noticed the text in the popup `div` is slightly opaque indicating it's also being affected by the masking `div`.

***How can I position the masking div to the absolute front?***

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/1/)**

Comment: You can just not make it a child http://jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/7/

Comment: Hey, this is great. what did you change to do that?

Comment: I changed #popupBox position to relative so z-Index has an effect. I gave #overlay a high z-index, but slightly less than #popupBox. And I made them siblings so the z-index has an intuitive effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c26Ez/

use `stopPropagation()` to make the event not bubble up the dom